# Cannot find issues with this Quicksort code

Tags: c++

I am writing a quicksort code in C++. The code works absolutely fine when I run it for small arrays but I am having problems when the number of elements are large, say 450.

My code looks like this: (Visual Studio used):

```
// algo_QuickSort.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;



int Partition(int master[6],int beg,int end)
{
    cout<<"entered partition..";
    int pivot=master[beg];
    int i=beg+1,j=end;
    do
    {
        for(;master[i]<pivot;)
        {
            i++;
        }

        for(;master[j]>pivot;)
        {
            j--;
        }

        if(i<j)
        {
            int temp=master[i];
            master[i]=master[j];
            master[j]=temp;

        }

        cout<<"i: "<<i<<endl;
        cout<<"j: "<<j<<endl;
        _getch();
    }while(i<j);
    _getch();
    cout<<"exited while..";
    if(i>=j)
    {
        int temp2=master[j];
        master[j]=pivot;
        master[beg]=temp2;
        cout<<"before return..";
        return j;
    }
}


void QuickSort(int master[10001],int beg,int end)
{
    cout<<"entered quicksort..";
    if(beg<end)
    {
        int flag=Partition(master,beg,end);

        QuickSort(master,beg,flag);
        QuickSort(master,flag+1,end);
    }
}




int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int A[10001];
    clock_t start,end;

    /*int A[6]={7,5,8,3,2};
    A[5]=numeric_limits<int>::max();

    QuickSort(A,0,5);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";*/
    for(int i=450;i<=10001;i+=450)
    {
        //cout<<"entered loop..";
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            A[j]=rand()%i;
        }

        A[i]=numeric_limits<int>::max();


        cout<<"here..";
        start=clock();

        QuickSort(A,0,i);
        //cout<<"out of qs..";
        end=clock();

        cout<<i<<","<<(double)(end-start)/CLK_TCK<<endl;
    }




    return 0;
}
```

Here you can see, the part which is commented out in the main function, is the test case for which the code run absolutely fine, printing the numbers in the ascending order. 
But when I run the code for large numbers, **It gets stuck in a kind of loop** So I wrote various `cout` and `_getch()` to track the values, here is the issue, [image]

The values of i is 26 and that of j is 137. Now my question is, since `i<j` , why aren't the values of i incrementing and j decrementing? 
The `do-while` loop is working but why aren't the values changing. Any ideas?

Comment: Start with a *much* smaller array, and use a debugger to step through the code line by line. Then eventual problems should become pretty obvious. Also build with extra warnings enabled and fix all warning messages.

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior since you are missing a `return` statement at the very end of `Partition`. Not sure whether fixing that will fix your problem.

Comment: Quicksort is known for it's large stack requirements, so most likely for a large input you're reaching the state of a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This block of code in `Partition` is flawed.

```
    if(i<j)
    {
        int temp=master[i];
        master[i]=master[j];
        master[j]=temp;
    }
```

The program runs forever if `pivot == master[i] == master[j]`.